# How do I mount a chip onto a stripboard?

Tags: audio, amplifier, stripboard

So, I just got my LM380 amp circuit working and I'm ready to mount it on my stripboard. But, my strip board divides all the holes into rows. **How am I supposed to mount the LM380 onto it if the rows go all the way accross the board?**

Comment: You must sever the traces under the IC with a sharp tool such as an Xacto knife.  Or don't use that kind of stripboard; use one that is suitable for IC's.

Comment: You could've said that in an answer :P Sounds good. I had no idea what board to get when I ordered it; It's my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Like this [image]

or this [image]

Veroboard is more useful than other prototype pcbs imho.

Comment: BusBoard makes some undeniably neat boards though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams considering some of the prototype board names get mixed up, which exactly is a busboard? The board above I call a vero or strip board.

Comment: http://www.busboard.us/